# UWP Wcf Service call async fails if called twice

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

Something I don't understand is happening in my logic, I receive no expectations but my application locks up.

Code:

```
ChatClient Service = new ChatClient();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = Service.AuthenicateAsync(T1.Text, T2.Text).Result;
    }
```

ChatClient Code:

```
public User Authenicate(string username, string password)
    {
        Clock.Restart();

        var User = new User();
        var Valid = false;

        try
        {

            var VerificationQuery = Provider.CreateAdoCommand("select count(AccessToken) as 'Verified' from Users where Email=@user and Password=@pass;", Provider.CreateParameter("@user", DbType.String), Provider.CreateParameter("@pass", DbType.String));
            var reader1 = VerificationQuery.ExecuteReader(username, password);
            using (reader1.Open())
            {//Check to see if the username and password is valid
                while (reader1.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (reader1.GetInt32("Verified").Value == 1)
                    {
                        Valid = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Valid)
            {
                var TokenQuery = Provider.CreateAdoCommand("select AccessToken, Timeout from Users where Email=@user and Password=@pass", Provider.CreateParameter("@user", DbType.String), Provider.CreateParameter("@pass", DbType.String));
                var reader2 = TokenQuery.ExecuteReader(username, password);
                using (reader2.Open())
                {//If the username and password is valid, retrieve the token and timeout period
                    while (reader2.MoveNext())
                    {
                        User.AccessToken = reader2.GetString("AccessToken");
                        User.TimeoutPeriod = reader2.GetDateTime("Timeout").Value;
                    }
                }

                //Check to see how old the timeout period is
                var timeSub = User.TimeoutPeriod.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                if (timeSub.Days < 2)
                {
                    //The token is too old, update the token, old token and timeout period
                    var TokenUpdateQuery = Provider.CreateAdoCommand("update Users set AccessToken=(NEWID()), OldAccessToken=@oldToken, Timeout=@newTime", Provider.CreateParameter("@oldToken", DbType.String), Provider.CreateParameter("@newTime", DbType.Date));
                    using (TokenUpdateQuery.Open())
                    {
                        TokenUpdateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery(User.AccessToken, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30));
                    }

                    var FinalQuery = Provider.CreateAdoCommand("select AccessToken, Timeout from Users where Email=@user and Password=@pass", Provider.CreateParameter("@user", DbType.String), Provider.CreateParameter("@pass", DbType.String));
                    var reader3 = FinalQuery.ExecuteReader(username, password);
                    using (reader3.Open())
                    {
                        while (reader3.MoveNext())
                        {
                            User.AccessToken = reader3.GetString("AccessToken");
                            User.TimeoutPeriod = reader3.GetDateTime("Timeout").Value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Database Query for user information
                var UserQuery = Provider.CreateAdoCommand("select FirstName, LastName, Email, DateCreated, AccessToken, OldAccessToken, Timeout, ConnectionId from [Users] where AccessToken=@token;", Provider.CreateParameter("@token", DbType.String));
                var reader4 = UserQuery.ExecuteReader(User.AccessToken);

                using (reader4.Open())
                {
                    while (reader4.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (reader4.GetString("AccessToken").Equals(User.AccessToken))
                        {
                            User.FirstName = reader4.GetString("FirstName");
                            User.LastName = reader4.GetString("LastName");
                            User.Email = reader4.GetString("Email");
                            User.AccessToken = reader4.GetString("AccessToken");
                            User.OldAccessToken = reader4.GetString("OldAccessToken");
                            User.TimeoutPeriod = reader4.GetDateTime("Timeout").Value;
                            User.DateCreated = reader4.GetDateTime("DateCreated").Value;
                            User.ConnectionId = reader4.GetString("ConnectionId");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        Clock.Stop();
        User.SecondsProcessed = Clock.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        return User;

    }
```

Service is a WCF service hosted on my web server that was added using Visual Studio. Inside my application I have two text boxes and a button. Clicking that button fires this method. The first time it works. Clicking it a second time and following a breakpoints it hits var temp ... but then just drops off and my application locks up.

Comment: What about service code?

Comment: If that will help sure, it is a decent size chunk of code.

Comment: Do you have logs as to what happens in the service?

Comment: No but I am going to change the service so that is catches errors and returns stores them into a database now.

Comment: I will have to come back to this question in the morning though it is late here.

Comment: I did a quick implementation on the service that catches any exception and logs it. The lock up still happens and no exception was hit.

Comment: Have you stepped through the service code or set some kind of trace statements to see where it gets stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I really cannot explain it. But changing the method to look like this works. I mean I can, because the Async method is being called you need to await it to get data. Therefore the async keyword needs to be added to the method.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = await Service.AuthenicateAsync("", "");
    }
```